# Saving changes in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor in a website and I want to use it as editor of the page itself. So the user goes to the page, modifies what he wants in the ckeditor textarea(s) and then he clicks 'save' or 'submit' and the page is modified (that page would be protected by a login, so only certain users could modify). 
Problem is I have no idea how to save the content of ckeditor in that same textarea that was modified, I tried looking around but everyone wanted to save data in a DB or send it to some other page.

I found 2 plugins that implement some save function but again, I don't know if I can use those to do what I want. ([Save plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/save), [Inline save](http://ckeditor.com/addon/inlinesave).

Hope you understood what I'm asking, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean like automatic save their input?

Comment: I have a page with some CK textareas, I modify the text inside them and I click save (one button for all or just one for each, not really important), when I click save it should update the text, so if I visit the page afterwards it's modified. (kind of an edit feature for a person that doesn't code/doesn't have access to the files themselves).

Comment: Sounds like you just need to post it to a DB, or use an AJAX call to do that.

Comment: Can you tell me what should I do with AJAX? I don't have much experience with this, I don't know how to get the content the user is writing (cause if I get from textarea I get the previous) and I also have some doubt on how to upload it to the same textarea he modified.

Comment: You are not making sense, basically what you WANT to do is upload the content to a DB and put the content the textarea.

Comment: That is how you would do that.